# make div with <a> clickable and div with no <a> non clickable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have this javascript code:

```
<script>
  $(".ucp_link").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    return true;
  });
</script>
```

and this html code:

```
<div class="ucp_menu"><div class="ucp_inner"><h4>all item</h4><div  class="ucp_link"><a href="p.php?p=">item1</a></div><div class="ucp_link">item  2</div></div></div>
```

I want to make div with  link clickable but not the one without  link.

Comment: $("div > a").click(function(){  });

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a591qxyt/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check whether the `ucp_link` element has a `link` element in it using `:has()` selector

```js
$(".ucp_link:has(a)").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  return true;
});
```

```html
<div class="ucp_menu">
  <div class="ucp_inner">
    <h4>all item</h4>
    <div class="ucp_link">
      <a href="p.php?p=">item1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ucp_link">item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the wrapping `div` is styled and that is why you want to do it like this.

You don't really need javascript for this, instead you can have the link cover the `div` using css.

For example:

```
.ucp_link {
  position: relative;
}
.ucp_link a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

If the wrapper `div` is not styled (no padding, etc.), you just need:

```
.ucp_link a {
  display: block;
}
```